# Android set Wallpaper - general sizes?

Tags: java, android, screen

I want to make an wallpaper app,
but I'm wondering if there is a general size of the image that should be?

Didn't find any answer, want to fit all of the smartphone's.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different phones have different resolutions So the wallpaper size would be different from one phone to another. Please read this link https://lifehacker.com/5657727/whats-the-deal-with-androids-weird-wallpaper-requirements

Thank you.
If you can find the device resolution you can figure out the dimensions of the wallpaper using,

2x the width and 1x the height

If a phone has a screen resolution of 480x854 the wallpaper has to be 2x the width (480 pixels) and 1x the height (854 pixels) = 960x854.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should google the screen size of the largest smartphones in the market and then it will be the way to fit all the phones . I suppose general size now is `720x1280`.

The biggest resolutions:

> Samsung Galaxy Note 8: 1440 x 2960 pixels Samsung Galaxy S8: 1440 x
>   2960 pixels LG V30: 1440 x 2880 pixels LG G6: 1440 x 2880 pixels Sony
>   Xperia XZ Premium: 3840 x 2160 pixels iPhone X: 1125 x 2436 pixels
>   (announced)

[Src](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-used-smartphone-screen-resolutions-in-2017)